# google Banner failed to load ad 3

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I was using google demo test bannerAd. Until yesterday it was working just fine. Yesterday the banner didn't load anymore, I did not change anything in the code. Reinstaling the demo did not show the banner either.
The InterstitialAd demo still works fine. What could possible cause this problem. 
 I recently upgraded Android Studio and the SDK to the latest version. Could this cause the problem.

Comment: Also, search in logcat by "Ads". You will be able to find messages related to Ads loading (and errors).  Check if ads and build gradle are pointing to latest Ads (play services)version as well

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely the same problem. Testing banner will not load. Intertitials and live ads are OK.
I have realized that AdMob is not showing preview banner even while creating new banner unit in my AdMob account. So I think the problem can not be at my side.

EDIT: "AdMob is currently experiencing a service disruption for its iOS and Android test banners. The engineers are working on it, but in the meantime, there's nothing wrong with your code." ([No test ads are loaded with AdMob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242442/))